# javascript - how to remove uri from a link

Tags: javascript

I got a link lie this

```js
url = 'http//mysite.com/product/id/122?u=12'
```

I want to turn that to this

```
'http//mysite.com'
```

remove all the uri and query string

How you guys do it?

Comment: theres plenty of libraries and examples on how to parse urls in javascript

Comment: couldn't you just delimit the string based on `'/'` and then just do a bit of extra logic for putting the `'http://'` back in?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) api

```js
let urlParsed = new URL("http://example.com/product/id/122?u=12")

let {origin} = urlParsed

console.log(origin)
```

Comment: TILSN! that's hot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` and string concatenation

```js
var url = 'http//mysite.com/product/id/122?u=12'
console.log(url.split('.com/')[0]+'.com')
```

Comment: thats not 100% reliable. what if i have `www.com.com` as the address?

Comment: Or what if the address is `www.google.co.uk/?s=some+search+string`?